# не работает $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

я новичок и разрабатываю магазин на Wordpress и WooCommercce
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Не могу понять в чем именно дело.
Итак, есть магазин http://new.sviter-ok.ru/, если в браузере зайти в админ панель хоть раз, то тогда добавление в корзину начинает работать. Но если сделать полную очистку кэша браузера и зайти в магазин то добавление в корзину не осуществляется, пока мы снова не войдем в админку сайта под администратором, и как только мы сделали вход админом, все опять начинает работать.

Теперь по коду.
У меня на каждой странице через header.php присутствует код:

```
global $woocommerce;
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    $productID = ($_POST["idtovar"]);
    $counttovar = ($_POST["counttovar"]);
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID, $counttovar);}
```

А кнопка добавить в корзину работает по коду:

```
$('.cart_add<? echo $variation_ID; ?>').click(function() {
var $idtovar = $(this).parent().parent().find('#sizeoncard').val();
var $counttovar = $(this).parent().find('#product_count').val();
console.log ($idtovar);
console.log ($counttovar);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '',
    data: {action:'call_this','idtovar':$idtovar, 'counttovar':$counttovar}
});

$("#cartblock").load("'' #cartblock");
```

Почему у меня не работает $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($productID, $counttovar); я никак не могу понять.
Перелапатил уже наверное весь интернет, хорошо хоть понял методом тыка, что код не работает если не заходили админом, как будто не хватает каких то переменных..... а потом при входе админом эти переменные загружаются в кэш и все начинает работать....
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.....
Спасибо

Comment: Пока можно сказать только одно - ajax сделан совершенно неправильно и это может вызывать массу побочных эффектов с установкой куки. Читайте, как правильно делать ajax в WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такой код.
`WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productID, $counttovar);`
А также используйте [стандартный механизм для AJAX запросов](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html)